# Mining wattage on Sapphire R9-390

Tags: mining, gpu, power-consumption

got my first rig coming online. 6x Sapphire R9-390. I have 2x 750w power supply. Am I good? Does anyone have these cards and know the watt draw? Thank you :-)

Comment: Holy, 6x R9-390 would suck around 1800-2400W. I have 2x 390X which pulls around 350W each.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 x Gigabye R9 390X + motherboard, CPU, drive + fans consume ~ 700 watts (measured with a power meter at the wall) - see [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether) . My GPUs are only slightly overclocked.

Your 390 and my 390X have a 275 watts thermal design power (TDP) - see http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Graphics-Cards/Sapphire-Nitro-Radeon-R9-390-8GB-Review .

I have a 850 watt 80+ Gold (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus) power supply - this has sufficient power to support 2 390X GPUs and the other components.

Your 750 watt power supplies may have enough juice to power 2 of your cards. Better to err on the side of caution and add a margin by using higher wattage power supplies.

Also note that AMD motherboards/CPUs consume more power than the eqivalent Intel motherboard/CPUs.

Comment: TDP ain't power consumption : https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/453630-graphics-card-tdp-and-power-consumption-explained/

Comment: Thanks @euri10 for pointing out the difference between TDP and power consumption. I've updated my answer.