# Is that worth to take the latest CPU to mine Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum-classic, hardware

I've been thinking that it's actually worth, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something there, as I looked into the last AMD 8x R9 390, that has a 250MH/s rate, which is pretty impressive, while it only costs 300€. So, shall I go for this GPU ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the cpu mining i suggest you to read this post : 
[Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether)

however before you buy a gpu to mine ethers consider to get an estimation about the Profitability , there is a lot of tool to do so i suggest you to try : https://badmofo.github.io/ethereum-mining-calculator/ or  https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

also you could get an idea about the hasrate comparaison between the GPUs used to mine ethereum : http://www.mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php?brand=amd

i made the calculation i've found that you will get about 29(>300$) monthly.

Comment: Well thanks, I needed that confirmation because I found 2 different hashrates for the same GPU for ethereum mining, I guess I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Could you confirm that the MSI 8x R9 390 hashrate please ? I'm only getting this number at  http://www.mininghwcomparison.com, otherwise everybody's saying it's about 30MH/s

Comment: you mentionned in your question that you card has 250MH from where you got this info?

Comment: From http://www.mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php as I mentionned it

Comment: 8x means 8 of those!

Comment: these data are submited by user so there is no way to check unless runing eth with gpu hash rate check